# JavaFX programs show only graphical nonsense under Java 8

Tags: macos, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

I have installed Scene Builder 2.0 on my Mac. When started (whether as standalone program or from within e(fx)clipse) it shows only a graphical mess (a fragmented mixture of my desktop wallpaper and program windows which have been on the screen recently). The menu bar works, but if I e.g. open the "about Scene Builder" window this window also contains that graphical nonsense. In rare occasions, the start screen looks somehow as it should but all characters are messed up with strange characters and after moving the window I get the same graphical mess as always.

I tried running the JavaFX programs from the JavaFX 2.2 demo bundle and found the same problems. They also have worked before I installed Java 8.

Even JavaFX programs run frum within eclipse show the same behaviour.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5 with all recent updates, Java 8 Update 25 and Scene Builder 2.0 on a 13" MacBook from 2008.

Previously, I had no problems with Scene Builder 1.x and Java 7 on this system (maybe I got OS updates in between).

I have tried reboots, reloaded Scene Builder from the website and reinstalled it, removed all old versions of Java. Nothing did work. The OS X software updater tells me everything is up to date.

Any Suggestions?
Anyone with similiar problems?